# Matrix Assembly Reference in iTextSharp with ASP.NET5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I'm trying iTextSharp in ASP.NETv5, I have a `PdfPageEventHelper` with an overridden `OnEndPage` with the following line:

```
_cb.AddTemplate(_template, pageSize.GetLeft(295), pageSize.GetBottom(36));
```

This throws an error: **The type 'Matrix' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.**

How do I fix this, do I need to add something to project.

**Edit**
Following CodingGorilla's answer, I've changed my web.config to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing"
          publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
          culture="en-us" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
  etc...
```

Yet the build still fails and mentions the 2.0.0.0 version.

Comment: Are you trying to run this on CoreCLR?

Comment: @CodingGorilla no, it's running dnx451 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, `System.Drawing` wasn't referenced by the project, added the reference to 4.0.0.0 and it worked

Comment: Ahh. So you have to do something like `"frameworks": {     "dnx451": {       "frameworkAssemblies": {         "System.Drawing": "4.0.0.0"       }     }   }`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I think the problem is that iTextSharp was written with/for .NET 2.0 and so it's looking for the 2.0 version of System.Drawing.  I've never tried doing this with `System.Drawing`, but I assume it would work the same; what you would want to do is add a `<bindingRedirect>` element to the web.config.  Check out this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx that talks about that.

I doubt iTextSharp has been tested with ASP.NET 5, so in the end you might simply not be able to use it since it's reliant on the older version of the framework.

Comment: ASP.NETv5 is currently (6 January 2016) not even released yet, it is still at RC1.

Comment: Not sure if I've done it right, but I'm still getting the same error. See the updated question. Should the intellisense / VS know that there is a redirect - because it's still highlighting it as an error and build is still failing.

Comment: Try: `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0"` see if that helps.  If not, then you might want to raise an issue on the ASP.NET github repo.

Comment: Any idea how I get any `System.Drawing` into the project? If I try `"System.Drawing": ""` in `project.config`, I get `The dependency System.Drawing could not be resolved.`

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse will iText be releasing a version for vNext? Any idea (rough estimate) when this might be?

Comment: You can find the answer to both questions on the iText blog. http://itextpdf.com/blog/itextsharp-and-uwp

Answer (score 0):

Actually you shouldn't need System.Drawing at all. I had the same issue in one of my classes. If you would apply what solved it for me, your code line would look like:

```
_cb.AddTemplate(_template, 1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, pageSize.GetLeft(295), pageSize.GetBottom(36));
```

This should not change the intended behaviour of your code, since your line would effectively call this line anyway.

I must admit that I still don't fully understand how System.Drawing comes into play at all. The method call shouldn't resolve to the System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix version if it gets two floats. The method signature containing the Matrix is even marked [Obsolete].